# Snapping doesn't work when moving UV Vertex to 1001/0-1 range

Tags: uv

I'm trying to move a group of vertices to the 1001/0-1 range.

In a tutorial I've read that I could make the vertices snap so that I can't move freely. This is what I tried to enable.

To do that, I checked the option "Display->Normalized".
However, I can still move the vertices freely, in the screenshot you can see that it's for example at X: 1.313, Y: 0.325

How could I make it snap well? I think a snap of 1, 1 could be good.

In the screenshot you can see that I tried other values, for example 100, 100, but that had not effect, I think.

Could anybody tell me how to enable the snapping that I'd need?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make UV islands locked in the texture space boundaries? It's not clear how Normalize is related here

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to do. The UV islands are already well organized, but they're for example in the 1002 range, so I need to shift them to the 1001 range. I read that "Normalize" would allow me to do so more easily. Is that not what is required here? Is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: I can't tell for Normalize, it will just convert displayed values for position of UV vertices, not avoid any movement anywhere, but you can use UVs > Constrain To Image Bounds in UV editor. Scale islands a bit down while they are inside texture space and then scale up until they are locked from scaling more